# Understanding the request lifecycle of a Play! application

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, bootstrapping

I am new to the Play! web framework, and in order to understand how it works, as well as how it compares with other web frameworks, I would like to be able to trace, in the Play! source code, the request lifecycle from start to finish. I will be using the Scala implementation of Play!.

Because most of my experience has been with PHP frameworks, I am used to starting with an index.php file in a web root directory and reading down through any included config/bootstrapping scripts, dependency injection handling, request routing, action dispatching, and finally view/response rendering.

I have not been able to identify a similar point of entry for a Scala/Play! application, and I would very much appreciate a push in the right direction. A walkthrough of the request lifecycle would of course be very generous, but all I really need is to be shown the entry point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default Play framework uses built-in HTTP server (based on [Netty](https://netty.io/)). So closest analogy with PHP will be that Play is both Apache and PHP.

PHP uses legacy 'CGI-like' paradigm: to serve single HTTP request, your program is started and after finishing serving request it is terminated. In CGI to serve an HTTP request webserver starts external program -- your script -- and returns its output. Older versions of PHP was designed only for CGI, in later versions other ways to interact with server, because CGI is very slow, but core principle remained the same.

Most of web application technologies use another approach: your web application is started one time then stays running, so one running instance of web application continues to serve requests (and can serve multiple requests in parallel). It does not die after serving a single request, as in PHP. This allows to consume much less resources required for starting application each time, and only just slightly harder to work with, because most of request processing in hidden inside framework, and your app only needs to expose controller methods that are called when request arrive and return response.

It also allows for more flexibility, for example background processing can be started right inside web app, no need for external server processes. Play has Akka library that is very convenient for this.

As more and more web applications use Ajax and REST approach, instead of serving heavyweight webpages each time, it becomes more important. And it is almost impossible to create realtime messaging backend with PHP that will have good performance, regardless of requesting technology (polling, long polling, iframe with multipart).

But if compared to PHP MVC frameworks, from point of view of developer that creates views, models and controllers, Play is very similar. Both in PHP MVC frameworks and Play framework calls controller method or function and this method should return response, views are usually templates and models are usually ORM bindings to relational database.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the file you mean:

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play-netty-server/src/main/scala/play/core/server/NettyServer.scala

Play is a Java application that starts listening at a given port. Listening is done using Netty library which understands different types of network protocols (most importantly HTTP). Once Netty knows whats happening it will give control to the Play framework.

The Play Framework will then use the Global file in combination with the Routes to determine what Action to invoke.

Comment: Now the above link is moved to following

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play-netty-server/src/main/scala/play/core/server/NettyServer.scala

Answer (score 1):

Play is more of a restful framework ( read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) rather than a typical template based frameworks like jsp jsf etc with a request lifecycle concept, although it does have templating support too. The basic idea is too have the interaction with server based on pure data like json and most of the code for update of dom structure is written in javascript and is done on client only which is actually more flexible and a lot simpler and efficent.

In play you just plainly create your methods for sending data to browser by defining a method in your scala class and mapping it in a **routes** file. Also like in a typical web development process you also place you html files in a public resource folder ( or create a template ) which will typically do a ajax call to that method when executed in browser.